# Trying to make a Node class function that takes an array of items and pushes them all to a linked list

Tags: javascript, linked-list

This is the code I have written so far. I don't think I am necessarily on the right track using a loop in the 'Node' function...

```
function LinkedList() {
  this.head = null;
  this.tail = null;
  this.length = 0;
}

function Node(...val) {
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      this.push(val[i])
    }
  }
  this.value = val;
  this.next = null;
}

LinkedList.prototype.push = function(val) {
    let newNode = new Node(val);
    if(!this.head) {
        this.head = newNode;
        return this.head;
    }
    let tail = this.head;
    while (tail.next !== null) {
        tail = tail.next;
    }
    tail.next = newNode;

    return this.head;
};
```

Here are the tests I am trying to run on it...

```
const newList = new LinkedList(5, 1, 2, 6, 8);
console.log(newList.head.value);
console.log(newList.head.next.value);
console.log(newList.head.next.next.value);
console.log(newList.head.next.next.next.value);
console.log(newList.head.next.next.next.next.value);
console.log(newList.head.next.next.next.next.next);
```

The output of the console logs is just "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value').

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong or where to head next? Thank you for your time!

Comment: What line of code does the error refer to?

Comment: All of the console logs at the end of the post!

Comment: How is `Node` supposed to get called?

Comment: On the first line of LinkedList.prototype.push = function(val)

Comment: The only call to `push` I see is *inside* `Node`.

Comment: It seems you've mixed up the responsibilities of the node and the list. The *list* should be taking the `val` array/arguments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `LinkedList` constructor does not have any parameters, so when you construct it with `new LinkedList(5, 1, 2, 6, 8);` those arguments are ignored.

You probably misplaced the argument processing, and put it in the `Node` constructor, while it should have been in the `LinkedList` constructor.

So move that code, and parameter definition, and it will work.

Some other things to improve:

- It is not necessary to do the `Array.isArray` check, since the `...val` parameter declaration will *always* give you an array when the function is called -- it could have length 0 when no arguments are passed, but it will still be an array.
- The `push` method should not have to go through a loop. You already have a `tail` reference, so use it.
- The `push` method should update the `length` property -- since you have it.
- The `push` method should not have to return anything. The modification is done in the `LinkedList` instance, and the caller should not really have to know about the `Node` instance that was created.

Here is the working version:

```js
function LinkedList(...val) {
  this.head = null;
  this.tail = null;
  this.length = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    this.push(val[i]);
  }
}

function Node(val) {
  this.value = val;
  this.next = null;
}

LinkedList.prototype.push = function(val) {
    let newNode = new Node(val);
    if (!this.head) {
        this.head = newNode;
    } else {
        this.tail.next = newNode;
    }
    this.tail = newNode;
    this.length++;
};

const newList = new LinkedList(5, 1, 2, 6, 8);
console.log(newList.head.value);
console.log(newList.head.next.value);
console.log(newList.head.next.next.value);
console.log(newList.head.next.next.next.value);
console.log(newList.head.next.next.next.next.value);
console.log(newList.head.next.next.next.next.next);
```

### Modernising

Since your code uses spread syntax, there is no reason why you shouldn't also use the `class` syntax, and the `for..of` loop.

And to avoid that the caller has to be aware of the `Node` instances, make your `LinkedList` class iterable using `Symbol.iterator`:

```js
class LinkedList {
    constructor(...values) {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
        for (let value of values) {
            this.push(value);
        }
    }
    push(val) {
        let newNode = new Node(val);
        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = newNode;
        } else {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
        }
        this.tail = newNode;
        this.length++;
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        let node = this.head;
        while (node) {
            yield node.value;
            node = node.next;
        }
    }
}

class Node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.value = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

const newList = new LinkedList(5, 1, 2, 6, 8);
for (let value of newList) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Wow... thank you so much!